# VIM Autoread file

Tags: linux, vim

I have the follow scenario.

I have  vim open on two files under directory X. That directory X will get deleted and recreated with the same two files (albeit different content)

How can I make vim automatically reload those files? (auto read does not seem to work when the directory  is deleted and recreated). Is there some plug-in for this you might recommend?

Comment: I have just checked, my vim have no problems with reloading such files using `:edit` or just while jumping to the next buffer using `:bn`

Answer (score 0):

I believe this command achieves the desired behaviour:

```
:autocmd CursorHold * :windo checktime
```

This auto command runs after a short period of cursor inactivity and causes each window to reload it's buffer if it has been externally modified.